# REST Client extension not sending form-data in VSCode

Tags: rest, visual-studio-code

I'm attempting to POST Authenticate using REST Client in vscode, but it isn't accepting my form-data. This is the http code from postman which appears to match specs on https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client but I don't understand why it doesn't like my credentials when submitting from vscode. Any help or pointers greatly appreciated.

```
Request:    
POST /myservicestack/authenticate/credentials HTTP/1.1
Host: services.mydomain.com
Accept: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: cdax7d61-8d8b-4f3q-b45v-74a240f33693

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UserName"

myemail@address.com

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Password"

My Password!

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="RememberMe"

true
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--



Response:
{
  "responseStatus": {
    "errorCode": "ValidationException",
    "message": "Validation failed: \r\n -- 'User Name' should not be empty.\r\n -- 
                'Password' should not be empty.",
    "errors": [
     {
       "errorCode": "NotEmpty",
       "fieldName": "UserName",
       "message": "'User Name' should not be empty.",
       "meta": {
         "PropertyName": "User Name"
     }
   },
   {
     "errorCode": "NotEmpty",
     "fieldName": "Password",
     "message": "'Password' should not be empty.",
     "meta": {
       "PropertyName": "Password"
     }
    }
   ]
  }
 }
```

Comment: What format is the server expecting the data in? Is it JSON or a multi-part form?

Comment: I checked postman and that piece was erroneous. I removed from Headers and still got a 200 in postman. Removed from my above snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool here is a red-herring and you should be checking what data format the server endpoint is expecting its data in. Typically REST services are expecting requests as JSON, but that is not universally true.

So for example (including both header and body):

```
POST https://example.com/comments HTTP/1.1
content-type: application/json

{
    "UserName": "myemail@address.com",
    "Password": "My Password!",
    "RememberMe":  true
}
```

If you want to see what the server may be receiving, then you can check against a service such as https://requestbin.com/ - just don't include any sensitive data.